# Redis Connection reset by peer when an object is greater than 1024kb

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, redis, google-cloud-memorystore

Context:

- Google Cloud
- Redis 6.x
- Client: Python 3.7, redis==4.4.0
- Python client error message: (104, 'Connection reset by peer')

A process has been working seamlessly until the Redis service got restarted today. After that, I cannot write any object to the managed Redis which is greater than 1024 kB. Anything smaller works fine.

I tried to check pages like https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/supported-redis-configurations for advice, but I could not find anything specific.

Any ideas?

Comment: Creating a new redis instance in GCP resolved the problem. It is alarming though what could have happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Connection reset by peer` typically means when a connection becomes disconnected, the next command issued on that connection will fail and redis-py will raise a ConnectionError to the caller. It is possible that the server is experiencing issues, or that there is a problem with the network connection between the client and the server when restarting the instance.

It is possible to change the limit at runtime using the [CONFIG SET](https://redis.io/commands/config-set) command or in a permanent way using the Redis configuration file `redis.conf`.You can refer to this [documentation](https://redis.io/docs/reference/clients/) for more information

Using [health_check_interval](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py#connections) eliminated most of these `Connection reset by peer` errors

You can also check this github [thread1](https://github.com/spotahome/redis-operator/issues/118) & [thread2](https://github.com/redis/redis-py/issues/1186)